# Set focus of items in a combo box

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have a couple of grids in my application and if the combo box that is in grid A has the focus, then A should be visible. Following code totally works fine for Text boxes, and even the combo box, but it doesn't work when I click on the drop down and try to click on an item in the drop down.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused, ElementName=FwInstances}" Value="True">
 <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

I am assuming the items in the combo box takes focus when I try to select it? Any explanation on what exactly happens here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Focus will be set to Popup content once you open and access the Popup content. So instead of Focused, you could bind to `IsKeyBoardFocusWithin` property of `ComboBox`, which remains true, even if you are in Popup.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin,ElementName=FwInstances,Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
 <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
</DataTrigger>
```